# Python list index out of range - minidom

Tags: python, xml, linux

Quick question, what is the correct solution when you see the error 'builtins.IndexError: list index out of range'?

This is in reference to another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549008/python-minidom-xml-parsing-dotted-quad-nested-children/) I've got going, but I'd prefer not to derail it.

Code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

net_xml = minidom.parse("network_objects.xml")

NetworkObjectsTag = net_xml.getElementsByTagName("network_objects")[0]

# Pull individual network objects
NetworkObjectTag = NetworkObjectsTag.getElementsByTagName("network_object")

for network_object in NetworkObjectTag:
    name = network_object.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].firstChild.data
    class_name = network_object.getElementsByTagName("Class_Name")[0].firstChild.data
    color = network_object.getElementsByTagName("color")[0].firstChild.data
    ipElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("ipaddr")
    ipaddr = ipElement.firstChild.data
    maskElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("netmask")
    netmask = maskElement.firstChild.data
    #address_ranges
    ipaddr_first = network_object.getElementsByTagName("ipaddr_first")
    ipaddr_last = network_object.getElementsByTagName("ipaddr_last")
    print(name,class_name,ipaddr,netmask,ipaddr_first,ipaddr_last,color)
```

The error that is generated after printing 6 lines is:

```
ipElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("ipaddr")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That means there are no `ipaddr` elements. You are rather stubborn about this minidom thing, aren't you? :-P

Comment: I'd *love* to use an alternative, but this just seems so simple/straight forward, minus my bumblings... Is there a way to add an exception into what I've already got? As far as I can tell ipaddr is in every section, but apparently I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huzah, got it working thanks to cwillu_at_work on freenode/#python. Helpful suggestions lead to:

```
    ipElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("ipaddr")
if ipElement:    
    ipElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("ipaddr")[0]
    ipaddr = ipElement.firstChild.data
maskElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("netmask")
if maskElement:
    maskElement = network_object.getElementsByTagName("netmask")[0]
    netmask = maskElement.firstChild.data
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the referenced list is empty.  In other words, the network object does not have an ipaddr tag.

To be safe, you need to save the result of `getElementsByTagName` to a variable and check the length before saving to `ipelement`  What you do when there is no `ipaddr` is up to you.

Comment: As Martijn is well aware, my python is horrendous. Would you mind showing me how to that correctly? :)

Comment: Or even pointing me in the right direction for documentation would be appreciated